# Toggle div visibility problem

Tags: jquery

How onclick some button, id=i_1, to toggle visibility of some div with id=d_1 (to show slide right while appearing)? I need to use JQuery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're after from your question, but perhaps something like this will get you started:

```
$("#i_1").click(function() {
    $("#d_1").animate({ width:'toggle' }, 500);
});
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/JsaPG/) showing that in action.

If you add some more information and some sample code to your question, it will be easier to provide a more accurate answer!

Answer (score 0):

The devious side of me wanted to code this dynamically

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Vcyj8/1

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" value="button 1" id="i_1"/><br>
<div id="d_1">div 1 text description</div>
<input type="button" value="button 2" id="i_2"/><br>
<div id="d_2">div 2 text description</div>
<input type="button" value="button 3" id="i_3"/><br>
<div id="d_3">div 3 text description</div>
<input type="button" value="button 4" id="i_4"/><br>
<div id="d_4">div 4 text description</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
  display:none;   
}

input {
  padding:5px;   
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$("[id^='i_']").click(function(){

  $("#d_"+this.id.substr(2)).slideToggle("fast");

})
```